# Stream with Tweepy : 'str' object has no attribute 'entities'

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I tried to get any tweet that contain images. But when I get tweet data in line `if media in data.entities:`, I get error `AttributeError: str object has no attribute entities`.

I tried adding to the line

```
twitterStream = Stream (auth, listener (), include_entities = 1)
```

but it does not work either

```html
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import pprint

consumer_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
consumer_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
access_token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
access_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"

class listener(StreamListener):
        def on_data(self, data):
                if 'media' in data.entities:
                        print(data)
                        #for image in  data.extended_entities['media']:
                        #print(image['media_url'])
        #return(True)

        def on_error(self, status):
                print ("error")
                print (status)
auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
tweets=twitterStream.filter(track=["#picture"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Tweepy passes the raw text data to `tweepy.StreamListener`'s `on_data()` method, which is used for handling the raw data from API (so you need to parse JSON string and construst `tweepy.Status` object).

If you handle normal status objects, you'd better use `on_status()` method but `on_data()`. This method takes Tweepy's normal Status object as an argument, so you can use this status object as usual.

So following code

```
class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):
        print('@on_status')
        print(type(status))
        print(status.text)

    def on_error(self, error_code):
        print('@on_error')
        print(error_code)
        if error_code == 420:
            return False

stream = tweepy.Stream(api.auth, MyStreamListener())
stream.filter(track=["#picture"])
```

will print like this:

```
@on_status
<class 'tweepy.models.Status'>
test1! #picture
@on_status
<class 'tweepy.models.Status'>
This is test picture tweet2! #picture
```

---

See also: [Streaming With Tweepy — tweepy 3.6.0 documentation](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/streaming_how_to.html)